# Nested for-loop error in r (package extRemes)

Tags: r, for-loop, package, nested-loops

I'm trying to make a 2-D vector in r and then plot it using the command `bloxplot()`.

```
numbers <- c(10,100,1000,10000)

for (i in 1:length(numbers)) {
e[i] <- c()

for(j in 1:100) {
a <- revd(numbers[i], loc = 0, scale = 1, shape = 0, type ="GEV")
b <- fevd(x=a, type="Gumbel")
c <- as.numeric(unname(b$results$par[2]))
d <- append(d,c)
}
e[i] <- append(e[i],d)
}
boxplot(e[i])
```

"revd" generates random variables, "number[i]" has different scenarios, "fevd" gives back the parameter value (location, scale and shape), they are both from the package "extRemes".

I'm trying append the vector to the vector (2D vector), but the error messages show up `Error: object 'e' not found` and `Error in boxplot(e[i]) : object 'e' not found`.

I've also tried putting "e <- c()" at the beginning:

```
numbers <- c(10,100,1000,10000)
e <- c()
for (i in 1:length(numbers)) {
e[i] <- c()
for(j in 1:100) {
a <- revd(numbers[i], loc = 0, scale = 1, shape = 0, type ="GEV")
b <- fevd(x=a, type="Gumbel")
c <- as.numeric(unname(b$results$par[2]))
d <- append(d,c)
}
e[i] <- append(e[i],d)
}
boxplot(e[i])
```

Then the error messages increased to:

```
Error in e[i] <- c() : replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In e[i] <- append(e[i], d) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

and

```
Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) : 
  need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Is there a different way of doing this without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got this right, this is one way of doing it. Rather than using `append()`, using the index of matrix or vector seems more R, to me at least. `replicate()` is also handy if you want to use the same function multiple times.

```
library("tidyr")
library("extRemes")
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")

numbers <- c(10, 100, 1000, 10000)
num_reps <- 100

out_mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=num_reps, ncol=length(numbers))

scale_out <- function(data){
  mod <- revd(data, loc=0, scale=1, shape=0, type="GEV") %>% fevd(type="Gumbel")
  return(mod$results$par[[2]])
}


for (i in 1:length(numbers)){
  out_mat[, i] <- replicate(num_reps, scale_out(numbers[i]))
}

ggplot(melt(out_mat), aes(x=Var2, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=Var2))
```

[image]

Comment: I have just tried out the code and it seems to have worked. Thanks a lot!